# getting black screen in 2-3 sec in mongodb-compass ubuntu

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql, nosql-injection

UBUNTU_MONGODB_COMPASS

1.first i install mongodb-compas(gui) and type in terminal `sudo dpkg -i file_location`
and after that click on mongodb icon the application is open but after 2-3 sec every thing disappeared

2.after reload same this occurs
i am using the latest stable version

3.i try remove and reinstall it
update the system
check the graphic card
but no use

Comment: If you launch `mongodb-compass` from the commandline of a terminal window, are there any error messages?